# How to determine the min_range and max_range for my RGB-D camera?

Tags: opencv, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I'm trying to do some basic depth detection and as described [here] by (http://answers.ros.org/question/10222/openni_camera-depth-image-opencv/?answer=14994#post-id-14994) by @fergs I need to know the min_range and max_range for my camera in order to convert my image. So how do I know that?

I am using a Carmine 1.09 and the website lists 0.35m as a minimum distance and 1.4m as a maximum one. Are these the values I should be using?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87681/how-to-determine-the-min_range-and-max_range-for-my-rgb-d-camera?/) by [Barbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/6891/barbas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use those values and filter out data beyond them. You probably won't see data below 0.35m, but you will definitely see data > 1.4m. With the 1.09 I've seen points out to ~6m, HOWEVER, note that the onboard calibration is really only valid for points in the 0.35-1.4m range, beyond that, the points become quite noisy and probably should not be used for anything like costmaps/octomaps.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Barbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/6891/barbas/) on 2013-10-06**:
By filter out do you mean ignore? Or is there some "soft" way to deal with the out-of-range data?